# Bash read command prompt value & use it with zenity

Tags: bash, zenity

I'm using openconnect for VPN. From command line openconnect asks for password (RSA token) and it's not possible (afaik) to "preenter" it (RSA value changes all the time).
Is it possible with bash to "read screen" - when openconnect prompts "password:" then i can bring up zenity and enter my RSA token value (password)?
Or is there another way to read "password:" prompt and use it with zenity?

Comment: [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)?

Comment: Sounds like you should get the RSA token first, then invoke openconnect. Does openconnect accept the password via stdin? If not, you'll need expect. Why do you need zenity anyway?

Comment: openconnect accepts password via stdin. Zenity is just to beautify things for others. No big deal.